# Wrong position UIScrollView content with statusbar

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to position `UIScrollView` at the top of screen to display a popup like Facebook Messenger
The Subview of `UIScrollview` is under the `StatusBar`.
How to position it correctly?

Issue:

[image: issue]

If I place `UIScrollview` under the `StatusBar`, it works

```swift
let StatusbarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Util.getScreenSize().width, height: StatusbarHeight + 50))
self.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height * 2)
let sub = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height))
self.addSubview(sub)
```

I expect that the subview is at the top of `UIScrollView`
Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVQqK.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try this on the `UIScrollView()`

```
self.contentInsetAdjustmentBehaviour = .never
```